# Spring boot: SSE Server Sent Events not working

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, rest, server-sent-events

In Spring Boot, when we try to send a Server Sent Event, it only sends an error event containing data: {"timeout":-1} when we try to connect, and the connection closes. The Spring Boot class is as follows

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class SsePushNotificationRestController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SsePushNotificationRestController.class);
    private SseEmitter emitter;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getString(){
        try {
            emitter.send("User connected");
            log.info("User connected");
            emitter.complete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Error while sending message to client: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return "placeholder";
    }

    @GetMapping("/emitter")
    public SseEmitter eventEmitter(@RequestParam String userId) {
        emitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
        return emitter;
    }
}
```

And our client code is as follows:

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/emitter?userId=testUser');

eventSource.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});

eventSource.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
    console.log("connection opened");
});

eventSource.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
    if (e.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) {
        console.log('closed');
    }
    else {
        console.log(e);
    }
    e.target.close();
});

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = e => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/test').then( data => console.log(data)).catch(data => console.log(data));
};
```

Immediately, an error is created before we can click the button to generate an event.
[image: error]
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What does your Spring boot terminal say? I think I need that information to address your program's error. By the way allowing cross origin resources sharing for requests from any sources (using wildcard) is a very very bad practice.

One possible reason of error is something's wrong when you create an instance of SSEemitter. (new SSeEmitter(-1L))

SSeEmitter(Long timeout) is creating server side event with set timeout it says. So if timeout is -1, I guess it would immediately be timed out and return timeout response. So it wouldn't be error, just working as written

Comment: The CORS is just for during development, it's a dummy program to get the hang of SSE before implementing it. The Spring Boot terminal just starts up and doesn't log anything in particular. When creating an SSeEmitter with value -1, you disable a timeout. I've also done it with large numbers and got the same result.

Comment: Does it show any error message on terminal/cmd that you're running Spring program on?

Comment: No it doesn't, there are no errors at all.